# Action of a group on a manifold: terminology of virtual character in equivariant homology?

Tags: representation-theory, manifolds, homology-cohomology, characters, equivariant-cohomology

I am looking for a proper terminology of the following. Additionally, it can be related to equivariant cohomology and I would like to know if there is any connection.

Given an action of a finite group $G$ on a manifold $M$, that is as nice as you want (ie, in a simplicial decomposition it permutes simpleces, etc.), how do you call this:
$$ \chi_G(M)(g):=\sum_i (-1)^i tr (g^*:H_i(M,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H_i(M,\mathbb{C})) $$

- Is it related to equivariant cohomology? Does it have a name there?

It is a virtual character, since it has some negative terms, but it is very specific because it involves a manifold (or simplicial complex); so I called it character of $G$ acting on $M$.

Comments on the absence of terminology are also welcomed.

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for $\chi_G(M)$ but $\chi_G(M)(g)$ is the Lefschetz number of $g$ (as a map $M \to M$), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: Indeed! I was looking for something more "group-theoretical" since I am focusing on group actions and characters when I talk about this. Thank you for your observation.